# WD My Passport Pro not accessible by Bose SoundTouch 20

Tags: nas

I have [Bose SoundTouch 20](https://www.bose.com/en_us/products/speakers/smart_home/soundtouch-20-wireless-music-system-bundle.html), a WD My Passport Pro that houses my music and runs Plex media server and lastly a standard cable modem/router that provides Wi-Fi and internet service.

The issue is that my Bose does not see my Plex media server and my music library.

I can open Plex on my Mac and it sees the media library. I have a shortcut on my Mac desktop that allows me to access the media library and add or delete files. The Bose system can play internet radio just fine.
My Mac connects wirelessly to the SSID that is generated by cable modem/router

The Bose is hardwired to the cable box/router and yhe Western Digital My Passport Pro has it own SSID and this is connected to the cable modem/router SSID.

Can anyone help me get the Bose system to recognize/see, have access to my media library that is on the WD My Passport Pro via Plex Media Server?

Comment: "The bose is hardwired to the cable box/router The Western Digital My Passport Pro has it own SSID and this is connected to the cable modem/router SSID" - So it sounds like your MBP is connected to a different subnet then your sound system, which is the reason, your sound system cannot find the NAS (which is connected to the same subnet as the MBP.

Answer (score 1):

After further research, it turned out that I had to assign the NAS a static IP and then everything worked.
Luckily I understand what was being required and was able to accomplish the task.